# ランダム配列の重複について

Tags: php, array

ある配列からランダムで取り出し、その値が被らないような機能を実装する場合、下記で行うとなぜか`NULL`と返ってきます。

```
</php

$name = array();
$name_list = array("mark","brown","cortony","cresta");

for($class=0;$class<=4;$class++){
  for($num=0;$num<=5;$num++){
    $newMember = array($name_list[$class] => $num);
      array_push($name, $newMember);
   }
  }

function class_sort (){
  for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $name = mt_rand(0,$name); //ランダムで取り出す
    echo array_unique($name); //重複を防ぐ
   }
  }

var_dump($name);
```

Comment: `class_sort` 関数がどこで呼びだされているのか不明ですが(関数パラメータも指定されていませんが…)、`mt_rand()` 関数の引数の指定に間違いがあります。もしかして `array_rand()` を使うつもりだったのでしょうか？

Comment: array_randという関数があるのですね、、調べていたらmt_rand()がランダムに取り出すと記事があったので使っていました。最終的にはランダムに重複せずに配列からキーをひとつずつ取り出すことです。

Comment: [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-rand.php) の場合、重複のない複数個のエントリを一度に取り出すことが可能です。

Comment: metropolisさん　array_randを使えば重複なしで配列から値を取り出すことが可能ということでしょうか。特にarray_uniqueを使う必要もないでしょうか。

Comment: はい、リンク先の後ろの方にサンプルコードが載っていますので、それを参考にすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: リンクの後ろの先とはどこを指しておりますでしょうか。サンプルコードを拝見できれば非常に助かります

Comment: [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-rand.php)の「例1 array_rand() の例」の部分です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4行目のソースコードのfor分のループ条件には

```
for($class=0; $class<=4; $class++){
```

とあります。これは$classが0~4までがループされますが、$name_listの要素数は4つなので0~3の範囲でループしないとエラーが起きてしまいます。

まずは、こちらを解決する必要があると思います。
おそらく意図されている動作は

```
for($class=0; $class<4; $class++){
```

ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 要素数が間違っていました。ありがとうございます。こちらに関しては修正しました。